# MongoDB/Node- Check if a document within a collection has a specific field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm new to node, express and mongodb and I have been looking at documentation and other StackOverflow for a few hours and still haven't managed to figure this out.

I'm using the MongoDB node.js driver.

I am trying to create a voting app where people can only vote once per poll. To do this I store their IP in the question document in the questions collection:

```
  var questionId = ObjectId(req.body._id);

  var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] ||
       req.connection.remoteAddress ||
       req.socket.remoteAddress ||
       req.connection.socket.remoteAddress;
  ip = ip.replace("::ffff:", "").replace(/\./g, "");

  db.collection('questions')
  .findOneAndUpdate({"_id": questionId}, {$set : {[ip] : true} }, (err, result) => {
    if (err) return res.send(err)
  })
```

However, I want to verify that the IP does not already exist in the question's document.``

So I want to check if `{'_id': questionId}` has: `{[ip]: true}` or even `ip` as a field.

The database entry looks like this (edited for clarity):

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "58caeb3402f11c2d66dc3f41"
    },
    "question": "Metallica or Megadeth?",
    "answer1": "Metallica",
    "answer2": "Megadeth",
    "answer1_votes": 14,
    "answer2_votes": 11,
    "127001": true
}
```

As we can see 127.0.0.1 has voted already, so I would want to stop that user voting again on that question.

I'm doing it with the IP as I want non-registered users to be able to vote.

I'm sure it's very simple, but I'm lost completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by moving the ip to a value position.

Something like `"ip" : 127001`.

You can now easily check for the presence of ip field and/ its value.

The below query will look for `ip` field in `question`, if its finds; do nothing, else set `ip` to the `question` document.

```
db.collection('questions').findOneAndUpdate({"_id": questionId, "ip": { $exists: false } }, {$set : {"ip" : 127001} }, (err, result) => {
    if (err) return res.send(err)
})
```

Comment: That would work except every new IP that votes would overwrite the old IP in place, unless I store them in an array under "ip" but I'm not sure how to access that either...

Comment: It will only add the new ip if it doesn't exist and does nothing when the ip already exist. Not sure why you think it will overwrite. What is your requirement ? Sorry I assumed you always have one ip for each question for current solution. . Do you need to store array of ips ?

Comment: You can use `db.collection('questions').findOneAndUpdate({"_id": questionId}, {$addToSet : {"ip" : 127001} }, (err, result) => {
    if (err) return res.send(err)
})` if you need to store array of ip's. This variant uses `addtoSet` opeator which doesn't allow duplicates. So you are guaranteed to have unique ips for a question at all times.